# Save the Resized image with webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I am using [this](https://github.com/odrick/webpack-images-resizer/) library to resize the image. My goal is to resize the images and create the sprite image with the resized images. So i need to save resized images into a directory.
Here is the code i am using.

```
var WebpackImagesResizer = require('webpack-images-resizer');
let list = [];
list.push({src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'temp'), dest: 'temp/resized'});
```

and in the plugins

```
plugins: [
        new WebpackImagesResizer(list, {width: 125}),
        new SpritesmithPlugin({
            src: {
                cwd:  'temp/resized',
                glob: '*.png'
            },
            target: {
                image: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/spritesmith-generated/sprite.png'),
                css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/spritesmith-generated/sprite.css')
            },
            apiOptions: {
                cssImageRef: "~sprite.png"
            }
        })
]
```

I can see the resized images in the browser URL but not in the File directory. Is it possible to save images
after the resize?

Thanks